# VS 2012 the project does not recognize the MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

[don't add controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42sOp.png)

[don't add View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agzGJ.png)

i am using MVC 5. TFS project connected. Later project Get latest version.
Result this ... Why that could be a problem?

Comment: Please explain something about the history of this application, the version of your IDE, and so on.

Comment: My question is why you're using VS 2012 at all.

Comment: LIkely the project file has lost one of the project type ids that tells VS it is an MVC project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your id has full Edit/Add access to project files in TFS. It seems all the files are locked as seen from image.

Other check is, verify that relevant MVC template is available in VS2012 to identify and run the project.

Comment: second thank you suggestions solves my problem :) installed https://www.microsoft.com/tr-tr/download/details.aspx?id=41532